# Webstorm IDE won't use correct port on localhost

Tags: localhost, port, webstorm

[image: Webstorm IDE Settings]

[image: Browser Result]

I updated WebStorm, restarted the IDE, everything, for some reason, launching the page through WebStorm doesn't launch on the specified port.

If I manually enter the correct port number into the URL, the page loads fine.

Comment: How do you launch it? Please check URL in your Run/Debug configurations (if you are using them). Please also check your Deployment entries (if you have defined them then initial URL will be taken from there).

Comment: The Run/Debug URL is the problem. How can I launch without the default URL being set there?

Comment: Well .. delete it (whole Run/Debug config) or alter it to suit your needs. The whole point or Run/Debug config is to have such info so that it can be launched with one click.